# Shopify api total sales

Tags: shopify

how can i get total sales from shopify store for api call? anyone have idea?I got total price by date but not total sale.

I need total sales by min and max date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer - `https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/order` and please share what you have tried.

Comment: I need total sales by dates and not only limited 250 i need all order's total sales by date distance and shopify only give me 250 orders total sales not more than that i need it as per my requirement. Thanks

Comment: Share the code you are using for a proper answer.

Comment: you can paginate orders by date and paginate at same time...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total amount of orders that you need for the range that you need, then get the ceiling of the order count divided by the amount per page (this will get you the total amount of pages you need to get). For example, if you have 730 orders for a day and 250 orders per page, you will need to get 3 pages of orders. You can then get the 3 pages of orders and add up the totals.

https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/order#count

Comment: Thank you.. but that's not my point i need count of all orders sale means total sales of all date distance orders.

Answer (score 0):

you have to loop the order list response and sum up the "total_price" field. If you need accuracy you have to subtract any refunds sum from your total sum.

Comment: I tried this and the sum of `total_price` indeed is the total order's amount in the dashboard, but there seems to be no `refunds` in the json object while there is some money subtracted in the dashboard by the name of "Returns". Do you have an idea what could be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a json object for refunds. In Python you can retrieve the refund information with `json_response['orders'][number_in_the_list]['refunds']`. Make sur to add to your GET request the `status=any` endpoint so you'll get `/admin/api/2021-07/orders.json?status=any` plus your other endpoints.